# Creating a custom navigation bar

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, theme

I successfully created a module which outputs "Hello World" on my CMS homepage. Now, I want to make this module a header / navigation bar which replaces the one of the blank theme. I also successfully created my own theme. So I am basically good to go but I don't know where to start. The structure and workflow of Magento completely confuse me. How do I change the styling of a certain block / module? How do I tell the module to be on the very top of all pages? I know it has something to do with the `default.xml` but... how? I got a "normal" HTML website with a gallery. I linked my shop there. I want to have a smooth transition from my HTML website to my magento shop meaning the design should match. So how do I get my header in magento to look like this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you declare something in default.xml , it will render in all the pages.

default.xml file looks like

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header">
            <block class="Er\Sample\Block\Test" name="sample.test" before="-" template="Er_Sample::test.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create block file with necessary functions

In test.phtml

```
<?php echo "Welcome message in all magento pages!!!"; ?>
```

It will display in all pages header section.

Answer (score 1):

Based off your input it sounds like you only want to change the styling?

If you want to make small styling changes you can extend the styling like so:

1. Create this file - `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less`
2. Add your styling here.
3. Compile your styling, if you don't know how you can read about it [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html).

If you want to overwrite all the navigation styling then follow these steps:

1. Copy this file into your theme - `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_navigation.less` -> `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/web/css/source/_navigation.less`
2. Make your styling changes in there
3. Compile your styling, if you don't know how you can read about it [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html).

Answer (score 1):

I may be late to give an answer for this question. But as a beginner of magento, I have the same problem as yours.
I have done it up to some extent and like to share the way I have done it.

1) I first create the basic layout structure of the header, using content tags in default.xml file
I placed this in the  **referenceContainer name="header.container"** tags in default.xml file. The reason is, navigation bar goes to the header section.

2) Then I have created a phtml file in magento, which includes the content of the navigation bar. This should be in the Magento_Theme module(Magento_Theme module is a customized module of the module_theme in vendor folder. This customized module should be in, app->design->frontend->vendor->yourtheme->Magento_Theme)

3) After that, call this phtml file using a  in between the layout structure where you want to place the nav bar.

e.g:**block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.nav.section" template="Magento_Theme::custom/head_navbar.phtml" before="-"**
Here I have created a head_navbar.phtml file which contains the content of nav bar

Hope this will help you.